# How to re-enable touchpad toggle in windows 10?

Tags: mouse

I have windows 10. Before upgrading, I could toggle the (Synaptics) touch pad via double tapping a soft button on the upper left corner of the touch pad, which (when disabled) lit up an amber light next to it. Now, after upgrading to Windows 10, double tapping the little depression on the touch pad does nothing. How can I re-enable this? I have tried looking for the setting in *every* tab of *every* window of *every* setting menu, Control panel and Windows 10 alike. Also, the driver is apparently up to date.
***To clarify, the touch pad is enabled-- I want to be able to TOGGLE this function again***

Answer (score 0):

There are sometimes toggle keys on your keyboard as well. an Acer laptop I once used requires users to press  Fn+F7 to activate or deactivate the trackpad. Your trackpad may have disabled itself during the upgrade.